# Loop through a list using a while statement

Tags: python

I want to loop through a list and terminate when I reach a certain value.
Something like:

```
ls = ['yes','yes','stop','yes']

while a in ls <> 'stop':
    print a
```

Would print:

```
yes
yes
```

I know I can do:

```
for a in ls:
    if a == 'stop':
        break
    print a
```

but it seems messy.

Comment: It might be "messy", but it is perfectly clear & does the job

Comment: Also, you should not be using `<>`.  That operator was deprecated in Python 2.5 and removed entirely from Python 3.x.  You should be using `!=` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use list indexing and slicing:

```
print ls[:ls.index('stop')]
# => ['yes', 'yes']
```

In a loop:

```
for a in ls[:ls.index('stop')]:
    print a
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> ls = ['yes','yes','stop','yes']
>>> for i in takewhile(lambda x: x != 'stop', ls):
...     i
...
'yes'
'yes'
>>>
```